# Unable to start wails app due to linking error: undefined reference to `gst_query_set_selectable`

Tags: go, ld, wails

I am trying to test out wails on my Opensuse workstation. I've installed all the dependencies, but when I run `wails dev` on a fresh project I am met with a linking error:

```
Building application for development...
  • Generating bindings: Done.
  • Compiling application: # changeme
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../lib64/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so: undefined reference to `gst_query_set_selectable'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`gst_query_set_selectable` is a function of `gstreamer` not `webkit` so to the extent that I would expect that function to be undefined in the webkit library, the error makes sense. That said, wails currently has 17k stars on github, so I'm sure this is not a problem with the library.